# How to model composite primary keys in the ER model?

Tags: data-modeling, entity-relationship, modeling

I am currently facing the challenge of modeling a composite primary key.

Here's an example:

`tblObjekt`:

```
Objekt_ID
objektTyp (raw material, assembly, finished product)
business year
month
```

==> The `Objekt_ID` in `tblObjekt` is not unique, but only in the context of the business year and month (composite primary key).

`tblGemeinkosten`:

```
Objekt_ID
business year
month
calculation type (standard, actual, target, etc.)
cost
```

==> The `Objekt_ID` in `tblGemeinkosten` is not unique, but only in the context of the business year, month, and calculation type (composite primary key).

How do I draw an ER model with Chen Notation for this?

Relationship: `tbLObjekt (1) => (1) tblGemeinkosten` ? (only individual items have exactly one overhead cost (but only if the composite primary key applies))

Thank you for all ideas and comments.

[image]